# Survey response view with big horizontal scrolling in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, list-view, survey-list

Having this issue when I view a Survey Response - the question is pushing the column incredibly wide horizontally and then just a very thin column to contain the answers.

Is there a way to have the question column not expand to the length of the question so the person viewing the results doesn't have to scroll horizontally to see the answers in a tiny column?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: any luck re-sizing your columns?

Comment: Sorry, haven't had a chance to try yet.  Will try in next 48 hrs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can over-ride SharePoint's column widths for any list. Unfortunately, you can't change this within "List Settings".

There are basically 2 options:

1. [SharePoint Designer](http://aanuwizard.com/2010/08/01/sharepoint-2010-how-to-change-width-of-list-column/)
2. jQuery (my preference)

jQuery method:

1. Edit your view aspx by adding a Content Editor Web Part
2. Insert something like the following jQuery into the CEWP and save your changes

```js
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(function(){
 $("tr.ms-viewheadertr th:contains('Inventor')", "#MSO_ContentTable").css("width", "50px");
 $("tr.ms-viewheadertr th:contains('Abstract')", "#MSO_ContentTable").css("width", "50px");
 });
</script>
```

Replace "Inventor" & "Abstract" with the correct names as per your columns. Also, adjust the "50px" width according to your preferences.

This solution was borrowed from many places, including [this blog](http://ravirapolu.blogspot.ca/2012/04/change-width-of-column-sharepoint-list.html).

**EDIT**

In order to adjust the width of your Survey response columns:

A. Upload a text file with the following jQuery to the root of your site collection (e.g. `http://yoursite/SiteAssets`) :

```js
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(function(){
 $("td.ms-formlabel").css("width", "20px");
 $("td.ms-formlabel").css("white-space", "normal");
 });
</script>
```

B. In your CEWP on the survey's DispForm.aspx, select "Edit Web Part" and add the URL that points to your new file uploaded in step A to "Content Link".

Note that `ms-formlabel` represents the "Question" column. You can adjust the width of this to pretty much whatever you desire. The `white-space:normal` bit will force the text in this column to wrap. You can similarly adjust your "Answer" column by modifying the CSS for `ms-formbody`.

Comment: Can't seem to get this to work... when I add the code to the CEWP it is just rendering on screen as code (not getting picked up as HTML - even if I first paste into notepad to strip any background stuff).     Also, this is the standard "View Response" page which has Survey Question on one side and Survey Answer on other side.  Do you know what those column names would be?  Thanks

Comment: @sayguh I updated the original answer with further instructions. Let me know if that works for you!

Comment: Thanks Phil, I'm away this week and will be trying on Monday

Comment: Right on, it should work. Again, ping me if you run into problems. Enjoy your week away!

Comment: Hey Phil, I'm almost there!  I got it to work on a single survey.  However, there are many surveys attached to this site.   How can I have this apply to all of the surveys in the site?  I've tried making edits to default.master and DispForm.aspx in the master files folder but I haven't been able to get it to work.  Could you provide some instruction on this?  Thanks!!

Comment: Editing your master page and/or globally editing dispform in this case is not advisable. However, this solution is fairly easily replicated. You just need to add a Content Editor Web Part to each of your Survey lists dispforms and link to the code file you have already created and saved. That way, if you ever need to update the code, you only have to do it in one place (in site assets). If that doesn't satisfy your needs, please approve my answer above and ask a new question about re-using this solution.

Comment: But this site has over 50 surveys..  also, the site owner is going to be creating new surveys all the time.   In this situation it seems like editing the master file for this specific site would make sense?

Comment: That's a new question. Wasn't part of the original question. It's a good one, you should ask it!

Comment: Help me out Phil!

Comment: @sayguh here are a few links to help you out. Good luck! http://pathikhrawal.wordpress.com/2011/06/24/custom-list-definition-adding-custom-list-pages-allitems-aspx-dispform-aspx-editform-aspx-newform-aspx/
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa544154(v=office.14).aspx
http://sharepointbuzzer.com/2013/10/19/replace-dispform-aspx-for-list-or-content-type/

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution to this issue is to simply use a "Return" or "Enter" to force a line break within the question.  This will cause the question to wrap.